# Regex validation - how to check for exactly 4 digits in Commcare integer field?

Tags: commcare

I'm using regex as validation, to check that year (integer field) entered is exactly 4 digits. My expression regex(., '[0-9]{4}') isn't working in Commcare, but when I checked at http://www.regexr.com/, [0-9]{4} does work. What am I missing in my Commcare function?

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of issues here.

Regexes are typically only used for string fields inside CommCare ("Text", "Phone number or Numeric ID", hidden variables, etc). If you want to do a validation on the "Integer" field, it's better to use numerical constraints. The way I would do this is:

`. >= 1000 and . <= 9999`

If you want to allow your 4-digit number to start with a 0, you should use the "Phone number or Numeric ID" data type. (Integers can't start with zeroes). Then, your regex will almost work.

Currently, this matches any string that contains a sequence of 4 digits *anywhere* in the string. If you want to match only strings that contain EXACTLY 4 digits, you'll need to add the ^ (start of string) and $ (end of string) characters. So the full expression would be:

`regex(., '^[0-9]{4}$')`

Happy matching!

Answer (score 2):

That regex should work, but it will only work on question types that store string values.

Because the question type stores an integer, regex won't work. But to validate a 4-digit value for an integer question, you could also use this expression:

. >= 1000 and . <= 9999

Also, as an aside, you can substitute \d for [0-9] in regular expressions. So if you had a string question that you wanted to validate exactly 4 digits with, you could use: regex(., '^\d{4}$')

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps CommCare doesn't support the `{n}` notation? (Not all regex implementations are the same). You could try `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` as an alternative.